# Passing keyword arguments within apply causes invalid syntax error

Tags: python, apply, keyword-argument

I am getting a syntax error when using **kwargs within the apply function:

```
def lookup_price(x,y, **kwargs):
    var1=x+y
    if IWM==True:
       var1=x-y
return var1
```

This is how I am using it:

```
 df['col1'] = df.apply(lookup_price, axis='columns', args=(1,2,IWM=True,))
```

I am getting this error:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the syntax of the df.apply(). [Click Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
You should not pass keyword args as a parameter in a tuple.
It will be passed as an attribute-value pair.

Something like this:

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lookup_price, axis='columns', args=(1,2,), IWM=True)
```

Comment: Ahh very nice, that makes sense. Thank you so much taurus!!

Comment: You can upvote it if it works so that it can be helpful to others as well.